# Postgresql equivalent to H2 DROP ALL OBJECTS

Tags: postgresql, h2

In **H2** database there is something called as:

```
DROP ALL OBJECTS;
```

which drops all existing views, tables, sequences, schemas, function aliases, roles, user-defined aggregate functions, domains, and users (except the current user). If DELETE FILES is specified, the database files will be removed when the last user disconnects from the database. (See [here](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#drop_all_objects))

How can I do exactly same thing in **Postgresql** ?

Comment: `drop owned by current_user`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I am getting this error: ERROR: cannot drop objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot drop objects owned by role postgres because they are required by the database system.

Please note that as I am using embedded-pg, I do not have any other user/role than the default one.

Comment: Which means you are using the super user as your application user - that is a really bad idea. You should create a regular user that creates and owns the tables for your application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Also even after dropping and creating new schema if we query "SELECT COUNT(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE ='VIEW'" , it still returns old count. What I am looking for is everything fresh.

Comment: That query will include all system views and views from other schemas so it is to be expected to still show many views. But again: why are you using the superuser to create your tables? That's a really bad idea? Are you working as `root` (or `administrator`)  in your operating system as well?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Even the query I provided above returns 0 count for you ?

Comment: Obviously it does **not** return 0 as there are over 50 system views alone which that query counts as well.